# Optimizing WordPress SQL query for older posts list

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

On my WordPress site, when a user pages far back in the list of posts, the queries end up taking a couple seconds. I'd like to bring this down. Here's the query that's being executed:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 846, 47
```

There are about 160k rows in the table. Here's a simplified version of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'publish',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'post',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the `EXPLAIN` result of the query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    ref type_status_date        type_status_date        62  const   41519   Using where; Using filesort
```

Ideally, I'd like to get rid of the filesort. Any tips?

Comment: what indexes do you have in place...?

Comment: The indexes are in the table schema in the question. There's a primary key on ID and a composite index on (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an index on the ordering column (post_date), without the index all 160k rows will be fetched, filesorted and then most of them discarded.

You might also want to look at more aggressive caching, storing result-windows in memcache or similar cache engine.

More tips on optimizing paginated displays at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/24/four-ways-to-optimize-paginated-displays/

Comment: Hmm, that was unexpected. If I add an index only on the ordering column and tell MySQL to use it using "USE INDEX (post_date_idx)", the performance is an order of magnitude better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have an index on `post_type`, `post_status` and `post_date`.

160k rows should not be a problem then.

Comment: That index already exists. See the table schema. "not be a problem" is relative. The current query takes around 2s to run and uses a filesort. I'd like to speed that up and eventually get rid of the filesort.

Answer (score 0):

When using `OR`, assure indexes are used on both sides of it.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* # change this to select only columns you need
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') or (wp_posts.post_type = 'post' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 846, 47
```

I'd also make `post_status` and `post_type` be enum. Also add a separate index on the ordering column (`post_date`), as in multi indexes only the first column on the left can be used as a individual index.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is just a guess, but anyway: I'd try to put `post_date` in the multi-column index first. Then the index should be sorted by the date and the result sorting can be done by traversing the index. I've not tried if it really works in MySQL though.

Answer (score -1):

Have look at http://www.slideshare.net/Eweaver/efficient-pagination-using-mysql. The recommendations there basically boil down to

- Have a suitable index that can be used both in the where **and** order by clause.
- Avoid usage of `COUNT()` (or its cousin `SQL_CALC_FOUND ROWS`) for displaying row (slides list a couple of UI changes or aggregation in separate field as necessary to achieve this).
- Do not use `LIMIT M, N` use `LIMIT N` (the way to achieve this is quite clever: If for instance you have the posts sorted by *primary key* `DESC`, then you can get the next page by adding a *primary key* less than the last element of your current page).

**EDIT:** The first point is covered in Peter Lang's answer, but please note, that if the pager allows sorting on other columns, then the index might not be sufficient.

Comment: Once in the presentation you linked it actually says "Do not let users go deep into the archives - link to [internet addiction page on wikipedia] instead". It basically solves the problem of `limit`ing by not doing it at all and sacrificing user experience.

Comment: @Raveren: There is a totally 26 slides in the linked presentation. The first nine detail the problem. The 10th, the one you're quoting, says that the *Simple solution* is to not allow paging (and then 'tongue-in-cheek' that you can redirect the user to said wiki page). The next 16 detail solutions. Are any of these off topic or incorrect? If that is the case, then please let me know.